# Adding javascript functions to web page

Tags: javascript

I've been messing around with making some simple chrome extensions, and everything was going smooth, editing html on a web page with some javascript is pretty straight forward. Now the problem starts when i want to add some javascript functions, for example to toggle a certain div etc. Here is my code

```
{
"name":"Warmane",
"description":"Some modifications to warmane forum.",
"version":"1.2",
"manifest_version":2,

"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://forum.warmane.com/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]

    }
  ]
}
```

content script

```
//Creating Elements

//Adding lates post button  
var nodeLi = document.createElement("LI");  
nodeLi.setAttribute("id", "latest_news");
var nodeA = document.createElement("A");               
var content = document.createTextNode("Latest posts");         
nodeA.appendChild(content);  
nodeA.setAttribute("class", "navtab");   
nodeA.setAttribute("href", "http://forum.warmane.com/search.php?do=getnew");    

//Adding mod cp button  
var nodeLiTwo = document.createElement("LI");  
nodeLiTwo.setAttribute("id", "mod_cp");
var nodeATwo = document.createElement("A");               
var contentTwo = document.createTextNode("Mod Cp");         
nodeATwo.appendChild(contentTwo);  
nodeATwo.setAttribute("class", "navtab");   
nodeATwo.setAttribute("href", "http://forum.warmane.com/modcp/"); 
//latest posts               
document.getElementById("navtabs").appendChild(nodeLi);     
document.getElementById("latest_news").appendChild(nodeA); 
//mod cp
document.getElementById("navtabs").appendChild(nodeLiTwo);     
document.getElementById("mod_cp").appendChild(nodeATwo);  

//Editing style 
document.getElementById("page-frame").setAttribute("style", "display: none");
document.getElementsByClassName("above_body")[0].setAttribute("style", "top: 170px");
document.getElementsByClassName("navigation-wrapper")[0].setAttribute("style", "top: 90px");
```

Now on this web page i want to edit i have a div

```
<p class="toggle">Toggle</p>
<div id="someDiv"></div>
```

which i want to show/hide every time i click on that `<p>`, and i have no idea how can i do that. Can anyone explain to me how can i go about this?

Comment: Are you asking about `addEventListener`?

Comment: You need to register an event listener on the element you are creating that triggers the hiding/showing.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Yeah i was talking about event listener, zfrisch solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4qqxr1dx/

```
document.getElementsByClassName("toggle")[0].addEventListener("click",    function() { 
var displayed = document.getElementById("someDiv").style.display;
(displayed == "none") ? document.getElementById("someDiv").style.display = "inline" : 
document.getElementById("someDiv").style.display = "none";

});
```

I added an event listener to the first DOM element with class "toggle". 
When you click on it it checks the display property of the element with the id "someDiv"

It throws it into a ternary operation(more info here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

The operation determines if it's displayed and then either hides or shows depending on the current declaration of the "display" property.

Comment: @Chilipepper Absolutely no problem! Good luck!

Comment: One more question:) I would like to save the user input, so for example if someone hides the div and when he reloads the page, div should stay hidden. My idea would be to save the input to local storage and then show or hide the div depending on that. What do you think?

Comment: @Chilipepper haha, sure. You've got the right frame of mind. I would personally use sessionStorage which only saves the variable until the browser is closed, but in the end that's up to you. Here's an example of the difference: http://html5demos.com/storage  - here's a tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_webstorage.asp